# Join is not removing the comma between elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

I can't figure out how to use join to get rid of commas between the images that are in the array. Using join is the only advice given on all the questions about removing commas. I have used this same append code (just different variables) in other projects and the arrays went on the screen with no commas, so I don't know why they are showing up in the first place.

```
for (i=0; i < adThree.length; i++) {
$sectionThree.append('<div class="three"> ' + adThree[i] + '</div>');
};

var adThree = new Array();
adThree[0] = ['<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/redborder125x125AdHolder.jpg"/></a>'];
adThree[1] = ['<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/greenborder125x125adholder.jpg"/></a>'];
adThree[2] = ['<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/orangeborder125x125adholder.jpg"/></a>'];
```

Comment: your loop is before you populate `adThree` - also, you are creating an array of arrays of strings ... try `adThree[0] = 'your string here';` instead?

Comment: You haven't shown how you tried to use `.join()`.

Comment: This is answered already. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements within the *adThree* array are arrays themselves. So, `adThree[0]` returns an array element like `['<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/redborder125x125AdHolder.jpg"/></a>']`. I am guessing you don't want that but want to have the picture within the `<div>`. For that, you need to declare your array elements without the square brackets, but as simple strings, like so:

```
adThree[0] = '<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img src="./resources/adimages/redborder125x125AdHolder.jpg"/></a>';
```

So your code should look like:

```
var adThree = new Array();
adThree[0] = '<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/redborder125x125AdHolder.jpg"/></a>';
adThree[1] = '<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/greenborder125x125adholder.jpg"/></a>';
adThree[2] = '<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/orangeborder125x125adholder.jpg"/></a>';

for (i=0; i < adThree.length; i++) {
    $sectionThree.append('<div class="three"> ' + adThree[i] + '</div>');
};
```

And also, be careful about what `$sectionThree` refers to. Usually, it is not the way to declare variables in JS. If you have `<div id="sectionThree">`, then you refer to this DOM object as `$('#sectionThree')`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me see that. I think I changed how I was originally doing it with arrays in arrays and left those. I have $sectionThree declared to equal what you show. That's how I do it to keep the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var adThree = ['<a href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/redborder125x125AdHolder.jpg"/></a>','<a 
href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/greenborder125x125adholder.jpg"/></a>','<a 
href="http://allinonehomeschool.com"><img 
src="./resources/adimages/orangeborder125x125adholder.jpg"/></a>'];

for (i=0; i < adThree.length; i++) {
    $sectionThree.append('<div class="three"> ' + adThree[i] + '</div>');
};
```

Comment: That appears to just be my code over again. In my code I do have the variable first. The code works. It's just that commas were appearing.